# how can i use a bash variable within expect script

Tags: expect

I am trying to do something basic using `expect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# define location variable; will be numeric eg 1234321
v_dir=$(cat /tmp/patch.txt)

spawn sftp micky.mouse@company.com@server.company.com 
expect "password :"
send "Chu6!0ck\r"
expect "patch"
send "cd $v_dir\r"
interact
```

Basically, I am trying to automate getting a patch from a remote patch server. The patch number is derived from a calling script - now I need `expect` to read that variable and `cd` to it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to use Expect syntax in an Expect program.

```
set v_dir [exec cat /tmp/patch.txt]
```

Comment: Sure. Calling out to cat isn't going to be a huge hit though.

Comment: set v_dir [exec cat /tmp/patch.txt] worked, so thank you !